# replacement for .get("transaction").commit()

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, single-page-application

I am following an old tutorial that has a method in the model `changedFavorite`:

```
App.Bookmark = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    favorite: DS.attr('boolean'),

    changedFavorite: function(){
        this.get("transaction").commit();
        console.log("favorite changed");
        }.observes("favorite")
});
```

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'commit' of null`

The method is supposed to be called when a checkbox in the template is ticked:

`{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="favorite"}}`

is their replacement code for `this.get("transaction").commit();` or `view Ember.checkbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have to use `save()`:

```
App.Bookmark = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    favorite: DS.attr('boolean'),

    changedFavorite: function(){
        this.save();
        console.log("favorite changed");
    }.observes("favorite")
});
```

Comment: that looks much moar nice